# needing to make only 2 decimal points instead of 4

Tags: php

i am trying to only have 2 decimal points on my if statement right now it shows 4 places after the decimal point depending if the subtotal * .45 = out to be.

```
if ($PAYMETHOD == $paypal)
{
    echo "Shipping & Handling = ".($GRANDTOTAL * .045);
    $GRANDTOTAL = $GRANDTOTAL * 1.045;
}
    elseif ($PAYMETHOD == $check)
{
    echo "Shipping & Handling = 0";
}
?><br />
```

this is my if statement needing it to be .$$ `<two decimal places only>`
right now it shows 4 places

Comment: use round and number_format functions

Comment: i tried that but it would only display the code in the form.

Comment: you're right i was just kidding?

Answer (score 0):

Number_format will do the rounding for you; use `floatval()` to turn back to a float after being converted to a string.

```
<?php

$PAYMETHOD = "paypal";
$GRANDTOTAL = 45;

if ($PAYMETHOD == "paypal")
{
    echo "Shipping & Handling = " . number_format(($GRANDTOTAL * .045), 2);
    $GRANDTOTAL = floatval(number_format(($GRANDTOTAL * 1.045), 2));
}
    elseif ($PAYMETHOD == "check")
{
    echo "Shipping & Handling = 0";
}
?><br />
```

Comment: why would this be $GRANDTOTAL = 45; ?

Comment: That was just part of my testing